# Issue with Bootstrap Rows throwing off Code

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what I am building. This works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/4xd47wcg/. The main goal is for the dots to connect to the prices but not be under the words.

When I add bootstrap to make it responsive for some odd reason the dots start going under the words see here: https://jsfiddle.net/619LLsqs/1/
Changed the color a bit to make it easy to see. For the life of me I cannot figure out what's causing the issue. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

```
<p>
  <span class='descripcion'>Trócola</span>
  <span class='precio'>56´72</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class='descripcion'>Junta la trócola</span>
  <span class='precio'>0´33</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class='descripcion'>Gamusinos en oferta c/u</span>
  <span class='precio'>6´47</span>
</p>




* {margin:0;padding:0;border: 0 none;position: relative;}

html, body {
  background: gray;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  font-family: muli;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  color: black;
}
p {
  background: inherit;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 40rem;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  color: black;
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .4rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ddd;
}
.descripcion {
  background: inherit;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-right: .2rem;
}
.precio {
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 4rem;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: .2rem;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 2;
}

h1 a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.55);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

Comment: For bootstrap you're best using columns. So have the first part of the text in a `<div class="col-xs-2"`, the dots in `<div class="col-xs-9"` and the price in `<div class="col-xs-1"`. It means it'll always scale pretty well.

Comment: I agree with @sringland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with background-color of `.descripcion` and `.precio`, in without bootstrap fiddle it's inheriting background-color of body which is `grey`, but in bootstrap fiddle it's inheriting transparent background-color.

Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/619LLsqs/2/

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!